# Source for Std Lib on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, vi, std, ctags

I recently started programming C on Mac OS X (10.7.4). I have the various headers for the stdlib in /usr/include, but was hoping to get the source code. This is mainly needed for my own learning, but I also wanted to generate Ctags against it for easy navigation in Vim.

Is it possible to get this from somewhere, if so from where?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what OSX uses, but for learning, you can't got wrong with glibc: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.13/